# Hiding Div without using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two Divs in html- Upper and lower

I want to show lower div if upper div is present else hide it.

Can we do it using CSS instead of Jquery or Javascript.

Note: No actions should be made on Upper div.. It will present automatically in some instances.

Comment: You should post some example HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Provided they're adjacent, you can do it with an [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) (`+`) by using a rule that hides the second one, then a rule that shows it with the combinator:

```
selector-for-the-second-div {
    display: none;
}
selector-for-the-first-div + selector-for-the-second-div {
    display: block;
}
```

**Live Example:**

```css
.second {
  display: none;
}
.first + .second {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">This is first</div>
<div class="second">This is second</div>
<hr>
<div class="second">This is second with no first</div>
```

If they're siblings but **not** adjacent, you can do the same sort of thing with the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) (`~`):

```
selector-for-the-second-div {
    display: none;
}
selector-for-the-first-div ~ selector-for-the-second-div {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @AmmarCSE: Thanks -- I realized that a moment ago and fixed it, hit refresh.

Comment: Very nice! Like this answer